# Exception in Application Cunstructor

Tags: exception, javafx

I want to write a code with javaFX (Snake game) but right now it's not complete yet because it doesn't consider `game Over` yet. I wrote this and it is not object oriented. When I sort it and try to make it object oriented, (exactly with last code that run correctly) it throws `Exception in Application constructor`.

the exception is :

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Main_Snake.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1819)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)
```

Someone said me to add :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

After adding that, I get a new Exception:

```
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class Main_Snake
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:910)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:187)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:747)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:426)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:822)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javafx.scene.Node.setTreeVisible(Node.java:8028)
    at javafx.scene.Node.updateTreeVisible(Node.java:8021)
    at javafx.scene.Node.<init>(Node.java:2372)
    at javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas.<init>(Canvas.java:100)
    at Main_Snake.<init>(Main_Snake.java:30)
    at Snake.<init>(Main_Snake.java:164)
```

Can someone check my code please?

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Nadia on 1/5/2016.
 */



public class Main_Snake extends Application{



    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(800, 600);
    boolean goNorth = true, goSouth, goWest, goEast;
    int x, y = 0; // marbut be apple
    boolean j = false;
    //    int gm_ov = 0; // vase game over shodan
    ArrayList<Integer> X = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> Y = new ArrayList<>();


    Snake snake = new Snake();
    Apple apple = new Apple();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {



        BorderPane b = new BorderPane(canvas);
        Scene scene = new Scene(b, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        //KeyBoard(scene);

        scene.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent e) {
                switch (e.getText()) {
                    case "w":
                        if (!goSouth) {
                            goNorth = true;
                            goSouth = false;
                            goWest = false;
                            goEast = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "s":
                        if (!goNorth) {
                            goSouth = true;
                            goNorth = false;
                            goWest = false;
                            goEast = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "a":
                        if (!goEast) {
                            goWest = true;
                            goEast = false;
                            goSouth = false;
                            goNorth = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        if (!goWest) {
                            goEast = true;
                            goWest = false;
                            goSouth = false;
                            goNorth = false;
                        }
                        break;

                }
            }
        });


        play(snake,apple);
    }

    public void play(Snake snake , Apple apple) {
        AnimationTimer timer = new AnimationTimer() {


            private long lastUpdate = 0;

            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {

                if (now - lastUpdate >= 40_000_000) {  // payin avordane sor@

                    snake.pos_S(); // har bar mar rasm mishe bad az move va ye sib ba X,Y khodesh rasm mishe tu tabe move dar morede tabe Point hast
                    apple.pos_A();
                    apple.random_Pos();
                    snake.Move(apple);

                    lastUpdate = now; // sor@
                }

            }
        };

        timer.start();

    }
   /* public void KeyBoard(Scene scene) {
    }*/
}

class Apple extends Main_Snake {


     public void random_Pos() {
         if (j == false) { // ye sib bede ke ru mar nabashe ( rasmesh tu rasme )
             do {
                 x = (int) (Math.random() * 790 + 1);
                 y = (int) (Math.random() * 590 + 1);
             } while (X.indexOf(x) != -1 && Y.get(X.indexOf(x)) == y || x % 10 != 0 || y % 10 != 0);
/*
                        inja aval chek kardam tu araylist x hast ya na ag bud sharte aval ok hala sharte do ke tu Y ham mibinim tu hamun shomare khune
                        y barabare y mast ag bud pas ina bar ham montabeghan va sharte dovom ham ok . 2 sharte akhar ham vase ine ke mare ma faghat mazrab
                        haye 10 and pas ta vaghti in se shart bargharare jahayie ke ma nemikhaym va hey jaye dg mide
*/

             j = true;
         }

     }

     public void pos_A() {
         GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
         gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);
         gc.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);

     }

     public void Point() {
         if (X.get(0) == x && Y.get(0) == y) {
             j = false;
         }
     }
 }

 class Snake extends Main_Snake {
    Snake(){   //cunstructor

        X.add(400);
        Y.add(300);

        X.add(400);
        Y.add(310);

        X.add(400);
        Y.add(320);


        X.add(400);
        Y.add(330);


        X.add(400);
        Y.add(340);
    }

    public void pos_S(){
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        gc.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        // keshidane mar (body yeki ezafe tar az adade morabaA mide)
        for (int i = X.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            gc.fillRect(X.get(i), Y.get(i), 10, 10);

    }
    public void Move(Apple apple){

        int Px = X.get(X.size() - 1);
        int Py = Y.get(Y.size() - 1);

        for (int z = X.size() - 1 ; z > 0 ; z--){
            X.remove(z);
            X.add(z , X.get(z-1) )   ;
            Y.remove(z);
            Y.add(z , Y.get(z-1) )   ;

        }

        if (goNorth) {
            Y.add(0 , Y.get(0) - 10);
            Y.remove(1);

        }
        if (goSouth) {
            Y.add(0 , Y.get(0) + 10);
            Y.remove(1);

        }
        if (goEast)  {
            X.add(0 , X.get(0) + 10);
            X.remove(1);

        }
        if (goWest)  {
            X.add(0 , X.get(0) - 10);
            X.remove(1);

        }

        apple.Point();        // emtiaz gerefte
        if ( j == false)    {
            X.add(Px);
            Y.add(Py);
        }

        if ( X.get(0) > 790 ){
            X.remove(0);
            X.add(0 , 0);
        }
        if ( X.get(0) <  0  ){
            X.remove(0);
            X.add(0 , 800);
        }
        if ( Y.get(0) > 590 ){
            Y.remove(0);
            Y.add(0 , 0);
        }
        if ( Y.get(0) <  0  ){
            Y.remove(0);
            Y.add(0 , 600);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you start the application, it creates an instance of `Main_Snake` (since that is the `Application` class.

Your `Main_Snake` class has a field (instance variable) called `snake` of type `Snake`, which is initialized inline to a new `Snake` instance:

```
public class Main_Snake extends Application {

    Snake snake = new Snake();

    // ...
}
```

Your `Snake` class is a subclass of `Main_Snake` (why?):

```
public class Snake extends Main_Snake { ... }
```

This means it inherits all the fields and methods of `Main_Snake`. So when you create a new `Snake` instance, it initializes all the fields defined in `Snake`, as well as all the fields inherited from `Main_Snake`. In particular, it creates a new object called `snake` of type `Snake` (since that field is defined in the superclass`Main_Snake`).

So, so far we have:

JavaFX creates a `Main_Snake` at startup. As part of the process of creating `Main_Snake`, a `Snake` is created (since `Main_Snake` has a `Snake`).

As part of the process of creating a `Snake`, a new `Snake` is created (the one `Snake` inherits from `Main_Snake`).

As part of the process of creating that `Snake` object (which, remember inherits from `Main_Snake`), a new `Snake` is created.

As part of the process of creating that `Snake` object (which, remember inherits from `Main_Snake`), a new `Snake` is created.

And I think by now you start to see the problem...

I can't really tell you how to fix this, as I have no real idea why you want `Snake` to be a subclass of `Main_Snake`. But you can't both have `Main_Snake` initializing a new `Snake`, and `Snake` a subclass of `Main_Snake`.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explain. You know , I had some Static variable things like x , y , my Arraylists , and canvas that I need to Access them in both Snake and Apple Class , use them check them or change and them for both. So I just remember inheritation. if I set them seprately in their Class I think they will diffrent with eachother, I think if I know the way of doing this , I can fix the problem that you said.